# override form save and return dictionary

Tags: django

I am trying to  override the form save method in order to return a dictionary.

forms.py

```
def save(self, commit=True):
   mobj = {}
   instance = super(_ObjectForm, self).save(commit=False)
   mobj['par_prefix'] = "string"
   if commit:
      instance.save()
   mobj['instance'] = instance
```

views.py

```
if form.is_valid():

        new_object = form.save()
        code...
        rfmodel =inlineformset_factory(dmodel,ModelsField.related_model,form=get_model_form(ModelsField.related_model._meta.object_name,model))
        prfmodel = rfmodel(request.POST,prefix=ModelsField.name,instance=new_object['instance'])

        if prfmodel.is_valid():
           new_object2 = prfmodel.save()
```

But when the form gets submitted, I receive an error

```
AttributeError at /inventory/InsertModelPageForm/Product
'dict' object has no attribute 'product_id'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventory/InsertModelPageForm/Product
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'dict' object has no attribute 'product_id'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py in save_new, line 911
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/teo/MYWORKSPACE/dev/Lemix',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
Server time:    Wed, 22 Jun 2016 06:36:54 +0000

>/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/teo/MYWORKSPACE/dev/Lemix/Inventory/views.py in InsertModelPageForm
                        new_object2 = prfmodel.save() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py in save
        return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py in save_new_objects
            self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit)) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py in save_new
        setattr(obj, self.fk.get_attname(), getattr(pk_value, 'pk', pk_value)) ...
▶ Local vars
```

and the line `new_object2 = prfmodel.save()` gets highlighted

Comment: You might want to show the full stack trace

Comment: I just updated the op, do you need anything else? thanx in advance

Comment: Maybe there is another way to archive what you are trying, Can you explain your goal?

Comment: when a inlineformset object form gets saved, a list is returned with the created objects, I need to have the form prefix of each object that was created from the inline

Answer (score 1):

> From django code:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    """
    Save this form's self.instance object if commit=True. Otherwise, add
    a save_m2m() method to the form which can be called after the instance
    is saved manually at a later time. Return the model instance.
    """
```

Check the **Return the model instance.** text.

You are trying to rewrite the save method, and that will cause the django ModelForm to crash when you try to submit the form.